# Average distance between two points

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded, convex set. Consider the problem of finding the average distance between two randomly chosen points from $S$: $$d = \mathbb{E}_{a\sim S}[\mathbb{E}_{b\sim S}[d(a, b)]].$$ Is it true that this average is achieved for every fixed point: that is, if we fix $a$, do we get the same result? Does $\mathbb{E}_{b\in S}[d(a, b)] = d$ for every fixed $a\in S$?

Comment: I have no ideea about the problem, but it feels weird that it got two upvotes in less than $3$ minutes to both question & answer and no one upvoted afterwards for the past $10$ minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be an obvious counterexample, can someone confirm if this is correct? If $S$ is a line of length $L$, then the average distance of two randomly chosen points is $L/3$. But if one of the points was fixed at an endpoint, the average distance would be $L/2$...